# Cut-off function with good property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $V\subset \subset U\subset \mathbb{R}^1$. Can we construct a Lipschitz cut-off function $f$ such that
$$
f=0 \quad \text{on} \quad V ,\quad f=-1 \quad \text{on} \quad \mathbb{R}^1 \setminus U,\quad f^2-|f'|\geq -C \quad \text{a.e.}\quad  \text{on} \quad  U\setminus V
$$
hold？

Is there a concrete example of such a function?

Could you please give me some help with details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really see how the last condition is a restriction. If $f$ is Lipschitz, then $f^2$ and $\lvert f' \rvert$ will be bounded anyway.

Comment: Try first to do this for $n=1$.

Comment: Start by reading your question more carefully, is there anything missing? For instance, did you miss the assumption that $U$ is open? What is $|f'|$? (Lipschitz functions are only differentiable almost everywhere. Did you mean the norm of the gradient at the points where it exists?) Also, explain what you know about cut off functions. Do you know about mollifiers and convolutions?

Comment: @HyperbolicPDEfriend Do you mean the function that I desired can be always obtained ? Could you please give me some details ? Thanks

Comment: Presumably, you want $C$ to depend only on $U$ and $V$ but not $f$, right?

Comment: @Deane C is a contant, you can take C=1.

Comment: It suffices to consider continuous piecewise linear functions. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, C>0 is obvious but it is difficult for C=0 . I  don't think that case can be done by thinking of continuous piecewise linear functions. @Deane